# how to make array of objects with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have an array like this `array : [ 50, 140, 60, 160 ]`

and i have an object like this

```
getcontract: {
  id: 1,
  supplier_a: "Supplier A"
}
```

i want to make array of objects, so it will turn like this

```
array : [
{ id:1, supplier_a: "Supplier A", price: 50 },
{ id:1, supplier_a: "Supplier A", price: 140 },
{ id:1, supplier_a: "Supplier A", price: 60 },
{ id:1, supplier_a: "Supplier A", price: 160 }
]
```

how to do that? this is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/damakuro221/h6tvzrdf/15/

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Note you're not adding properties to an array, you're creating an array of objects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, i was kind of confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each value inside your array to a new object.

Inside the new object we copy the contract with `...contract` and then we append the price via `price: num`

```js
const contract = {
  id: 1,
  supplier_a: "Supplier A"
};

const arr = [50, 140, 60, 160];

const result = arr.map((num) => {
  return {
    ...contract,
    price: num
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A map should be enough

```js
const array = [50, 140, 60, 160];
const getcontract = {
  id: 1,
  supplier_a: "Supplier A"
}

const result = array.map(price => ({ ...getcontract,
  price
}));


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's clearer if you..

```
array.map(price => { return { 
                         _id: contract._id, 
                         supplier_a: contact.supplier_a, 
                         price: price 
                       } 
                    })
```